# SQLSERV and PHP not working... Cannot create a connection to the database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have gone through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn425064%28v=sql.10%29.aspx), and to my knowledge it works. (`phpinfo()` shows it on the list of added extensions)

I have this code that I got from MSDN. I made some modifications to it so that it could work with my SQL Server and database. The Database is there, and it running.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(-1);
?>
```

^^ In the `<head>` block.
No errors were reported.

```
<?php
   $serverName = "(local)"; 
   $database = "{db}";

   // Get UID and PWD from application-specific files. 
   $uid = "{user}";
   $pwd = "{pass}";

   try {
      $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database = $database", $uid, $pwd); 
      $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
   }

   catch( PDOException $e ) {
      die( "Error connecting to SQL Server" );
   }

   echo "Connected to SQL Server\n";

   $query = 'select * from {table}'; 
   $stmt = $conn->query( $query ); 
   while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){ 
      print_r( $row ); 
   }

   // Free statement and connection resources. 
   $stmt = null; 
   $conn = null; 
?>
```

Here is the `var_dump()` of `$e` in the catch block.

```
PDOException Object ( [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'. [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 28000 [file:protected] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sandbox\sfactor\sandbox.php [line:protected] => 20 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sandbox\sfactor\sandbox.php [line] => 20 [function] => __construct [class] => PDO [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => sqlsrv:server=;Database=SFactor [1] => sa [2] => 7536SqL ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => [errorInfo] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'. ) ) Connected to SQL Server Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sandbox\sfactor\sandbox.php on line 31 Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sandbox\sfactor\sandbox.php on line 31
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `sqlsrv` or `PDO`? Your title suggests the former but the example suggests the latter

Comment: Try dumping the actual error codes and message rather than just `die( "Error connecting to SQL Server" );`

Comment: Did you try `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);` this, the example taken from http://www.php.net//manual/en/pdo.connections.php replacing with your credentials, of course.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I just did that now.. More descriptive error messages followed. I now get failed to log in for user sa. (Tried sa instead of normal User)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am using MSSQL 2014. No MySQL.

Comment: If you are using the correct `uid and pwd` then try removing the spaces around `Database = $database` So do `Database=$database`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Tried it, to no avail.

Comment: I have added the `var_dump($e)` to the OP

Comment: $uid = "{user}" - do you literally have a user in the database called '{user}'? Did you mean "{$user}". The name of the database looks odd as well.

Comment: @RyanVincent, anything in {} are taken out. They have values on the actual running version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

So it's fixed.. 
The problem was `$serverName = "(local)";` was giving the problems.

All I had to do was, `$serverName = "localhost\MSSQL2014";`

Thanks to everyone.